# How do I save to database from a model Method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a field in my User model called `unique_identifier` which I want to populate with the outcome of the `create_unqiue_identifier` method below.

How can I add this to the database for the user?

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_secure_password

    def create_unique_identifer
        loop do
            self. unique_identifier = SecureRandom.hex(5) # or whatever you chose like UUID tools
            break unless self.class.exists?(:unique_identifier => unique_identifier)
          end
        // add something here to store unique_identifer to the database?
    end
end
```

Comment: You mean the [`#save`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/save) method?

Comment: Rails has built-in behaviour called `has_secure_token`, maybe that is something that could work for you.

Comment: Are you sure you even want to do this in Rails? If you're using Postgres you can use the `pgcrypto` module and its native uuid type. On MySQL you can use the `UUID()` function.

Comment: I'm using postgres yes. I want the unique identifier as I want to give each user a unique email address like '0c5s5sd1@example.com'. So I have the `create_unique_identifier` method, then another method `create_email` which appends the `unique_identifier` to '@example.com'. Apologies if this seems like an odd way to do it, I'm still getting to grips with rails. I have the methods in my User model, so when a API request is made to my rails api I route to these User model methods, just struggling how to then save the outcome of these methods for the correct user.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured this out, I have to return the result of `create_unique_identifier` back to my controller. Then within the controller I can save the `unique_identifier` for the User.

```
    def create_unique_identifer()
        loop do
            self. unique_identifier = SecureRandom.hex(5) # or whatever you chose like UUID tools
            break unless self.class.exists?(:unique_identifier => unique_identifier)
          end
        unique_identifier
    end
```

to save I then added the below code to my controller:

```
      if @user.unique_identifier.nil?
        unique_identifier = @user.create_unique_identifer
        @user.update(unique_identifier: unique_identifier)
      end
```